# Keras Custom Loss Function: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have the following custom tf function:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def top10_accuracy_scorer(y_true, y_pred):

    values, indeces = tf.math.top_k(y_pred, 10)
    lab_indeces_tensor = tf.argmax(y_true,1)
    lab_indeces_tensor = tf.reshape(lab_indeces_tensor, 
                                    shape=(tf.shape(lab_indeces_tensor)[0],1))
    lab_indeces_tensor = tf.dtypes.cast(lab_indeces_tensor,dtype=tf.int32)
    equal_tensor = tf.equal(lab_indeces_tensor, indeces)
    
    sum_tensor = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(equal_tensor, tf.float32))
    top10_accuracy = sum_tensor/tf.cast(tf.shape(lab_indeces_tensor)[0], tf.float32)
    
    return top10_accuracy
```

It works fine as a metric in my model but when I try to use it as a loss function I get the error: `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable`. Obviously, some part of it is not differentiable but I cannot figure out how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Working example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

X_temp = np.random.uniform(0,1,(1000,100))
y_temp = np.random.uniform(0,1,(1000,10))
y_temp = np.argmax(y_temp, axis=1)
y_temp = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_temp)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(y_temp.shape[1], input_shape = (X_temp.shape[1],), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=top10_accuracy_scorer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_temp, y_temp)
```